# How to add change listener to message property of task in javaFX

Tags: javafx, task, changelistener

I am using JavaFX task to execute time consuming code which processes a number of items in a for loop.
The progress of the task is indicated by a progressbar which is updated from inside the for loop.
However along with the progress bar I also have some labels which indicate the progress in terms of the total items to be processed and the current item being processed.
I was trying to bind the `messageProperty` of task to the labels `textProperty`, however I have multiple labels that need to be updated and `messageProperty` can hold a single `String`.
I considered updating the `messageProperty` with comma separated values string and then splitting the string like this

```
label1.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty().toString().split(",")[0]);
label2.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty().toString().split(",")[1]);
label3.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty().toString().split(",")[2]);
```

however I get an error

```
The method bind(ObservableValue<? extends String>) in the type Property<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

So I am considering adding a `ChangeListener` to the `messageProperty` and updating the labels from inside the `ChangeListener`

Can someone please help me to determine which approach is the best and how to write the `ChangeListener` for `messageProperty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
label1.textProperty.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> task.getMessage().split(",")[0],
    task.messageProperty());
//...
```

or

```
task.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldMsg, newMsg) -> {
    label1.setText(newMsg.split(",")[0]);
    // ...
})
```